# Map as a value for Query Param in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http

I am using a model for query params for a GET call.

```
public class Model{
      private Map<String, Object> myField;
      public Map<String, Object> getMyField(){
          return this.myfield;
      }
      public void setMyField(Map<String, Object> myField){
          this.myField = myField;
      }
}
```

And my controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/view",method= RequestMethod.GET,produces={"application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<ViewResponse>> view(Model p_request) {}
```

This is the request I am hitting `http://localhost:8080/view?myField={"states":"23"}`. I get bad 400 bad request and also

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the
>   request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC
>   3986

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Pass the object as a *query param* and then parse that object in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of intermediate `Model` class if there is no pressing need of it. You can use simply `Map` to map all input request param, for that you need to use spring mvc `@RequestParam` annotation, like

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Object>> view(@RequestParam Map p_request) {
}
```

and then you dont need to send quoted http request, request will become:
`http localhost:8080/view\?states=23`

Comment: So I basically need a query param of filters type where I can apply filters on many things.
eg:  filters = {"states":[active, inactive], "name":["ABXC", "PQR"]} 

Coming to why model actually there are other query params also. This is one of the query params whose key is `myField` but value itself is a map

Comment: ok @sagarr, also you can use for in Question : public ResponseEntity view(@RequestParam Map p_request) {
}  :)

Comment: Any perticular need that you need to pass that as json only, I mean u can use comma separated req params like `states=a,b&name=x,y`